# Sort an array of random numbers that have already the random number

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.*;

public class FIRSTPROJECT {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub



        static int[] firstArray, secondArray;

        static int con = 100;

        firstArray = new int[con];
        secondArray = new int[con];
        for (int i = 0; i < con - 1; i++) {
            firstArray[i] = (int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE * Math.random());;
            System.out.println(firstArray[i]);
            Arrays.sort(firstArray[i]);
        }
    }
```

The problem is that the type `int` does not correspond to `int []` after I pass it through the for loop

Comment: Except for the random number turnout to be 0 and 1, the multiplied value will always exceed the `int` limit

Comment: In the code in your question, `secondArray` is not used. Do you really need it? Are you trying to populate `firstArray` with random integers and then sort it? Is `firstArray` meant to be a local variable in method `main()` or is it supposed to be a member of class `FIRSTPROJECT`?

Comment: hi, second array will be used to create a similar array that will be sorted with insertionsort function but i need to get the firstArray first

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't have static inside of a method in Java. Secondly, the reason it is not sorting is because you are sorting it on firstArray[i] <-- this is not an array anymore, this is accessing the element at index i. Change your code as follows:

```
    int[] firstArray, secondArray;

    int con = 100;

    firstArray = new int[con];
    secondArray = new int[con];
    for (int i = 0; i < con - 1; i++) {
        firstArray[i] = (int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE * Math.random());;
        System.out.println(firstArray[i]);
        Arrays.sort(firstArray);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use static variable inside of static method.
Here i had attached updated code for adding random numbers into array and then sort it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] firstArray, secondArray;
        int con = 4;
        firstArray = new int[con];
        secondArray = new int[con];
        for (int i = 0; i < con - 1; i++) {
            firstArray[i] = (int) (Integer.MAX_VALUE * Math.random());
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(firstArray));
        Arrays.sort(firstArray);
        System.out.println("Sorted"+Arrays.toString(firstArray));
    }
}
```

Also attached output for same.

**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.7\bin\java.exe" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=63743:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath D:\untitled\out\production\untitled Sample
[1865181155, 340923400, 1281005722, 0]
Sorted[0, 340923400, 1281005722, 1865181155]
```

**